# lim inf version of sequential criterion

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that if $f$ is a continuous function, then $\lim f(x_n)=f(\lim x_n)$, provided $\lim x_n$ exists.

Can the same thing work for $\lim\inf$? i.e. is it true that $\lim\inf f(x_n)=f(\lim\inf x_n)$, provided $\lim\inf x_n$ exists (which it always does).?

Thanks for any help.
I am trying to see if I can use this property in another proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The problem is sequences with more than one sublimit (point of convergence). $\liminf$ is the smallest such sublmit, but you have no guarantee that $f$ keeps the order of the sublimits intact. It may map some other sublimit to a point *lower* than the $\liminf$. Example below.

---

Take $x_n = (-1)^n$ and $f(x) = -x$.

Then, $\liminf x_n = -1$, and $f(-1)=1$. However, $\liminf f(x_n) = -1$.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent example!